# Best option for recognize clicked item in listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In My app I have a listview and a button for creating albums (By clicking on button app a new item adds to listview) and by clicking on each listview items you can go to that album and upload/take your photos for display.

for saving and retrieving photos after take/pick I use SharedPrefrence for saving and retrieving Image Path. as you see I Can't have a predefined SharedPrefrence, so I use this method which I made it myself: in listview OnItemClickListener I make this "str" String and by putting it in a intent It will be passed to my first album page:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

        String str = new String("album" + arg2);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Albums.this, MainA.class);
        intent.putExtra("extra", str);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And after this process I use this string in my new activity for my sharedprefrence like this:

```
String str = getIntent().getExtras().getString("extra");
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(str, 0);
```

in this way everything does perfect but except when for example User Deletes the second album (second Item in Lisview) which cause third album to be the second and since I used the position int for specify the sharedprefrence it will totally destroy.

I don't know if you could understand my way =), But if you did what should I do to avoid this?

this way even is the best way for my purpose?

thanks.

---

EDIT:

deleting listview item code:

```
public void deletetask(String t){
    if (null == itemArrey) {
        itemArrey = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    itemArrey.remove(t);

    //save the task list to preference
    b1s = getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    try {
        b1s.edit().putString("array", ObjectSerializer.serialize(itemArrey)).commit();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: post the coe where the deletion occurs

Comment: First try to replace this line : String str = getIntent().getString("extra");.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I added the code but I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: @Haresh aren't these same?

Comment: I understand the logic, but passing int as album number will not work. Instead, create one folder on memory device (which is private to your app) and put album folders into that. Now, if album gets deleted, simply delete the folder and populate list again with folder names (i.e. album names) this will work.

Comment: You pass value as string to direct intent and try get from intent bundle this wrong way that y i tell to replace ur code with my code which is given as above comment

Comment: @Paritosh if I do this, how can I find witch item clicked so I could load images from that folder? I mean what should I do in list.onclicklistener and in album pages? maybe a example or even a resource would be great. thanks.

Comment: Your listview is containing names of folder. You can use that as parameter. Is it ok if I give you entire code after some time say 2-3 hours?

Comment: It would be awesome :). But a resource or explaining the steps is enough though. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Man this makes no sense. Why cant you use sql? Even if you are going to use SharedPreferences for store, you should create a Object named album:

```
Class album {
    private long id;
    private String path;
}
```

Then on OnItemClickListener arg3 will be the id (you must pass it on getId of the adapter class, make a custom adapter extending baseAdapter that user a list of albums, this is not hard).